# What does it mean to "Change DATA_ROOT to point to the PASCAL images"

Tags: python

I'm going through an installation of https://github.com/TheLegendAli/DeepLab-Context and got this instruction.

Here is the how-to-install info:

**Performance**

DeepLab currently achieves 73.9% on the challenging PASCAL VOC 2012 image segmentation task -- see the leaderboard.

**Pre-trained models**

We have released several trained models and corresponding prototxt files at here. Please check it for more model details.

The best model among the released ones yields 73.6% on PASCAL VOC 2012 test set.

**Python wrapper requirements**

Install wget library for python

`sudo pip install wget`

Change DATA_ROOT to point to the PASCAL images

To use the mat_read_layer and mat_write_layer, please download and install matio.

**Running the code**

`python run.py`

---

I don't know what DATA_ROOT is - is it an environment variable? something else? How would I access it and change it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a global variable in [`run.py`](https://github.com/TheLegendAli/DeepLab-Context/blob/master/run.py#L14):

```
# MODIFY PATH for YOUR SETTING
EXP='voc12' #dataset
NET_ID='vgg128_noup' #model name
NUM_LABELS=21
YEAR = 'VOC2012'
DATA_ROOT='/media/ali/VOCdevkit/VOC2012'
```